# Pagination does not work after Ajax call in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, kaminari

I am using plugin Kaminari for pagination. I am Ajaxifing my application and I encountered a problem. I have a form with paginated data plus form for filtering data (both via Ajax). At start pagination works good, and the url's for particular pages are '/admin/rooms?page=X'. After ajax filtering those url's change for '/admin/rooms/filter?page=X'.
I can specify the action to trigger when paginating by:

```
<%= paginate @rooms, :params => {:controller => 'rooms', :action => 'index'}, :remote => true %>
```

but then variable @rooms gets resetted in index and I paginate unfiltered data again.

Any ideas how could I fix it?

Here's some code

- **rooms_controller.rb**:

  ```
  class Admin::RoomsController < AdminController
  def index
          @rooms = Room.all
          @rooms = Kaminari.paginate_array(@rooms).page(params[:page]).per(5)
          @filter_values = [['Room number', 'room_number'], ['Person count', 'person_count'], ['Room class', 'room_class']]
  end

  def filter
          case params[:filter_by]
          when 'room_number'
                  @rooms = Room.find(:all, :conditions => ["CAST(room_number AS VARCHAR) LIKE ?", "#{params[:filter_value]}%"])
          when 'person_count'
                  @rooms = Room.find(:all, :conditions => ["person_count LIKE ?", "#{params[:filter_value]}%"])
          else
                  @rooms = Room.joins(:room_class).where("lower(class_name) LIKE '#{params[:filter_value]}%'")
          end

          @rooms = Kaminari.paginate_array(@rooms).page(params[:page]).per(5)
          respond_to do |format|
                  format.html { redirect_to admin_rooms_path }
                  format.js
          end
  end
  ```
- **index.html.erb**:

  ```
  <%= label_tag 'Filter:  ' %>
  <%= form_tag(filter_admin_rooms_path, :remote => true) do %>
          <%= select_tag :filter_by, options_for_select(@filter_values) %>
          <%= text_field_tag :filter_value %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Filter', :disable_with => 'Filtering..' %>
  <% end %>

  ...

  <div id="rooms_list">
          <%= render 'admin/rooms/shared/rooms_list' %>
  </div>
  ```
- **_rooms_list.html.erb**:

  ```
  <div id="paginator">
          <%= paginate @rooms, :remote => true %>
  </div>
  <table class="table_listing" style="width: 60%">
          ...
  </table>
  ```

Comment: This really is a guess (hence, not an answer for now) but looking at your code I'd assume that you have to pass the filter variables around through Kaminari's `params` attribute for the `#paginate` view method. Something like `<%= paginate @rooms, :params => { : filter_by => params[:filter_by], … }, :remote => true %>`. You probably might want to use a helper method, which checks that the parameters are actually set etc..

Comment: I had my doubts about passing arguments already to index method (somehow I failed on this on first attempt), but I went for it again after Your post and... it works. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by passing parameters again to index and forcing paginate to route to 'rooms#index', not the current page (not visible cause of Ajax though).

- **_rooms_list.html.erb**:

  ```
  <%= paginate @rooms, :params => {:controller => 'rooms', :action => 'index'}, :remote => true %>
  ```

Parametrs are passed to index by GET from the present params variable.

- **rooms_controller.rb**:

  ```
  def index
          if params[:filter_value].nil?
                  @rooms = Room.all
          else
                  @rooms = test_filter(params[:filter_value])
          end

          @rooms = Kaminari.paginate_array(@rooms).page(params[:page]).per(5)
          @errors = flash[:errors] || []
          @filter_values = [['Room number', 'room_number'], ['Person count', 'person_count'], ['Room class', 'room_class']]
  end

  def filter
          case params[:filter_by]
          when 'room_number'
                  @rooms = Room.find(:all, :conditions => ["CAST(room_number AS VARCHAR) LIKE ?", "#{params[:filter_value]}%"])
          when 'person_count'
                  @rooms = Room.find(:all, :conditions => ["person_count LIKE ?", "#{params[:filter_value]}%"])
          else
                  @rooms = Room.joins(:room_class).where("lower(class_name) LIKE '#{params[:filter_value]}%'")
          end

          @rooms = Kaminari.paginate_array(@rooms).page(params[:page]).per(5)
          params[:authenticity_token] = nil
          params[:commit] = nil

          respond_to do |format|
                  format.html { redirect_to admin_rooms_path }
                  format.js
          end
  end

  def test_filter(val)
          rooms = Room.find(:all, :conditions => ["CAST(room_number AS VARCHAR) LIKE ?", "#{val}%"])
          rooms
  end
  ```

test_filter is to remove/rename of course. I nil some parameter that I think shouldn't be passed in params to the next page when paginate.